# My manager used my colleague to tell me I was moving jobs

Tags: communication, manager

I will be moving teams within my company in around 6 weeks. I am happy with the position that I will be taking, from what I have heard of it. I am also content in my current role however.

I was told this news by a colleague in my current team. My manager told this person and asked that they informed me. I was happy with the conversation with my colleague.

While I have a lot of time and respect for my colleague, I couldn't help but think it was strange that my manager didn't tell me.

My colleague told me if I had any further questions I could ask my manager.

This was a week ago and my manager still hasn't mentioned the subject of my move, directly or indirectly.

For additional background, my manager has only ever provided me with performance feedback upon my request. I will try to find out from my colleagues if this is his management "style" or if I should take it personally.

I guess my question is should I be raising this with him or HR or just keeping quiet as it's expected behaviour?

Comment: Make up question.  Such and such told me I will be moving teams.  Is it OK to tell my current team members I am moving?

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps your manager is grooming your colleague for a more supervisory/managerial position and was simply using this information exchange as a training opportunity.

Don't look to your colleagues to find things out. Look to your manager. Even if it is his management "style", he needs to address your situation with you himself. I would imagine (though I have couldn't say with certainty) that your colleagues do not have the authority to grant or direct any change in your status, and as such likely could not notify you of any change with any binding effect.

Speak to your manager directly. You obviously have questions regarding the new situation, so follow the instructions and ask him directly. While you're asking him about it, ask him politely about the reasoning for having your colleague inform you. Let him know you'd have been more comfortable with it all if it'd just come from the manager as you would expect it to.

Comment: Also better to speak to your manager directly as any details of the change that the OP are relying on should come as directly as possible.  If colleauge gets a crucial detail wrong, management is less likely to stand behind what was said by a non-manager.

Answer (score 2):

> I guess my question is should I be raising this with him or HR or just
>   keeping quiet as it's expected behaviour?

While it's certainly odd for a manager to do this, there is no benefit to you in taking this "issue" any further.

Since your manager hasn't exactly been communicative in the past, it sounds as if this is just part of his style.

There is no benefit for you in taking this to HR. It would be awkward at best, and might make you seem like a complainer at worst.

If this manager will continue to manage you after the move, find a quiet time to chat with him. Talk about the move, and try to see if you can understand his style better, so that his style won't be so unsettling for you in the future.

If this manager will no longer manage you after the move, then forget about it and enjoy the prospect of a new manager in 5 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Leveraging the people and the teams around you is a good idea to gauge information if that was typically the objective, however not recommended unless we are indeed grooming team members to take on a leadership or management roles, I have a good rule in life that I abide to, trust, but verify so it's a good idea to bring it up in conversation at the right time or depending on your work environment's approach to topics like these (it is somewhat serious) a meeting request is great to take charge. Regardless, bad move on the manager's part.